# Pointwise Convergence Given a Measurable Set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I have the following question that I am confused on.

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of real-valued functions on $X$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
>
> $\mu\left\lbrace x\in X\:\big|\:|f_{n}(x)-f_{n+1}(x)|>2^{-n}\right\rbrace<2^{-n}$.
>
> Show that $\{f_{n}\}$ is pointwise convergent almost anywhere on $X$.

*My understanding:* I know that I have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in X\setminus E_{0}$, where $E_{0}$ is some measurable subset of $X$ for which $\mu(E_{0})=0$. Other than this, I'm not sure where to take this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the set of all $x\in X$ such that $\lvert f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)\rvert > 2^{-n}$. Use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that $\mu(A) = 0$ where $A = \limsup A_n$. If $x\notin A$, then there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $\lvert f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)\rvert \le 2^{-n}$. Show that this implies $\{f_n(x)\}$ is Cauchy for all $x\in X\setminus A$. Therefore, $\{f_n\}$ pointwise convergent outside the null set $A$.